# How to add textures to a black and white map in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, texture, maps

in general, I have a height map, I need to apply a texture on it so that the texture weakens on black and intensifies on white, how?
[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "weakens" and "intensifies"?

Comment: Sound like curves but the wording is a bit open.

Comment: Look up "Displacement Maps" for Photoshop. They are designed to create a bump map based upon greyscale images. As this question stands, to me, it's way too broad and shows little effort in actually solving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to apply a texture on it so that the texture weakens on black and intensifies on white

I really doubt you want what you are describing you want.

Adding a texture will be confusing... but ok. Let's take a look.

1. I added a wood texture as a background.
2. Your map is in multiply mode.

Done. The texture is not visible on the black and it is more visible on the white.

[image]

On the second image, I modified the levels of the image, so you can see more clearly the wood... if that is possible.

---

If what you need is to transform this height map into some 3D shaded "terrain" use it as a displacement map on a 3D software.

For example Blender. https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=blender+using+displacement+maps